# Bug with V8 and DEPRECATED ES5 publishing project

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script that gets data from Google SpreadSheets combined with some encryption and outputs it's results as plain text. The script worked perfect at previous version of google API. I've not changed anything in it but it works buggy in new V8 scripting engine. I'm switching to old deprecated standard and it works ok in dev mode. But after publishing it I'm checking the link but it still is broken. I suppose that you have a bug in publishing mode(not use the old version of script mode). And I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Levon - you are probably misled - SO is not Google's support platform, we just help out with coding issues. If you are sure that the feature works on Rhino and not on V8, please, submit a bug (this is such a major change that bugs are, I think, expected) report on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) if you haven't done so. P.s. V8 is an engine, not a standard :) Be sure to be as detailed as possible and provide a code sample reproducing the issue (you can do so here as well and we at least can confirm whether this is a bug or not)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're are right. I press submit issue but I was redirected to stack overflow. I missed that thing and I found it right after post this question. So I suppose it is not in the right place for a bug report

Comment: No worries - if you provide details on the exact problem you face, with code samples and all, we might be able to help you mitigate the issue (there are quite a few changes that apply when migrating to V8 that are not bugs, but may break the existing codebase (see [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#v8_migration_procedure))